# Differentiation via definition

Tags: derivatives

If $f'\left(-\dfrac{3}{2}\right)=2$, then compute the following 
$$
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{f(2)-f(2+h)}{h}
$$

Indeed the limit above equals $-f'(2)$, but I cannot figure out the connection between this and the given $f'$.

Comment: Is this everything you know about $f$ and $f'$? I don't think the given info is enough.

Comment: Yes. That is all given.

Comment: You cannot calculate $-f'(2)$. Take $f(x) = 2x$ and $g(x) = x^2+5x$. The derivatives $f'(x) = 2$ and $g'(x) = 2x+5$ satisfy your assumption, but they have different values at $2$.

Comment: We don't have sufficient information to determine the limit.

Comment: $f'(-1.5)$ has nothing to do with $f'(2)$. Continuity and Differentiability is a very local property.

Comment: You cannot comment anything. Say $f(x)=2x \;\;\;\; \forall x<0$, and $f(x)=\text{(anything)}\cdot{x} \;\;\;\; \forall x>0 $ . How are you supposed to calculate $f'(2)$?

Comment: Thanks guys. I thought the same.